# Cannot get menu buttons lower than centered logo

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the menu buttons down while keeping the logo at the current position.
See https://www.amplifiedhistory.com/home

Currently I have this code snippet to keep menu center:

```
@media (max-width: 959px){
.menu-wrapper div[class*=col-lg-] {
 text-align: center;
}
}@media (min-width: 960px){
.menu-horizontal ul.menu-smart > li > ul:not(.mega-menu-inner) {
 margin-top: -50px !important;
}
.menu-smart ul > li > a, .menu-smart ul > li > ul > li > a {
    padding: 5px 0;
}    
}
#menu-item-117811 .drop-menu {
  width: 250px !important;
}

#menu-item-117811 li a {
    width: 250px;
}

#menu-item-117811 li a .menu-btn-table,
#menu-item-117811 li a .menu-item {
  width: 250px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I've tried everything from position relative, to flex and margin-top but none of those bring the buttons down.
Hope anyone here has a resolution

Comment: I'm not smart enough to understand what you want, but I did notice that the social buttons half disappear behind the scroll bar when the screen is between 940 and 1270 pixels wide. Using Firefox here.

Comment: Down where, exactly? Can you trim your code into a [mre] of your nav bar? This is probably something you could fix with [flex attributes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) but it's hard to tell when adding things in the browser inspector.

Comment: @AStombaugh Basically down 100-150 px. 

I did figured out one piece of snippet that sort of works, but doesn't bring down the menu buttons enough: 

Code looks like:
body[class*=hmenu] div:not(.menu-accordion) > ul.menu-smart > li,
.main-wrapper ul.menu-smart.menu-horizontal > li, .navbar-cta ul.menu-smart > li {
    align-items: flex-end;
}

As for the trim code. I'm not sure what you're asking. I'm still learning I guess :-)

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yeah I know, that's also something I'm still working on. On most screen resolutions it shows nicely, but somewhere between desktop and mobile there's a grey area and the socials fall of